# Откуда функция time() берет значение?

Tags: php, дата, timestamp

```
$date=mktime(10,30,0,7,4,2020);
echo date('Z',$date);
```

Выводит 10800, что равнозначно 3 часам разницы с Гринвичем. Но как он узнает в каком часовом поясе был сохранен этот timestamp? Timestamp ведь не хранит часовой пояс.

Comment: Зато сервер хранит, а код выполняется на сервере.

Comment: То есть сервер хранит для всех значений timestamp свой локальный часовой пояс?

Comment: Нет. timestamp это число и там нет часового пояса. Часовой пояс появляется при переводе этого числа в дату/время. Пример:  14554389000 (число условное) в Москве полдень, а в Лондоне 9 утра. Таймстэмп одинаковый, а время разное.

Comment: Как я понял, сервер хранит часовой пояс в своих настройках. Типа директивы date.timezone и в случае перевода числа timestamp использует эту директиву для получения времени в других часовых поясах? timestamp ведь хранит локальное время, а не время по Гринвичу.

Comment: timestamp это __число секунд__ прошедших от 1 января 1970 года. В любом месте планеты в одно и то же время это число секунд __одинаковое__.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было сказано в коментариях, timestamp хранит число секунд прошедших с 1 января 1970го года. Для хранения времени нам не нужен часовой пояс, он используеться только для отображения. При отображении уже учитывается часовой пояс и выдается результат в зависимости от часового пояса.

P.s Это относиться не только к php.